# How Can I create executeReader class

Tags: c#

Sir,

I have a connection class for ExecuteNonquery

```
public class Connection
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public void connclose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    public Connection()
    {
       conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ADMIN-PC;database=sample;Integrated security=true");
       cmd = null;
    }
    public void nonquery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

In this same way I have to create a Executereader class also....What changes i should apply for that

I have a class too

```
public void insert(string sid, string cid, string state)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertState");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cid;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = state;

        conn.nonquery(cmd);

    }
```

Comment: Where is the problem? t

Comment: `ExecuteReader` is method exposed by `SqlCommand`. Google some examples of `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: I fail to see the point of that class but just call ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonQuery and return its result.

Comment: My problem I want to create a Executereader function same like my Executenonqury function which i mentioned above

Comment: public void nonquery(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
its for Executenonqury...i want to create same one for executereader
    }

Comment: For `insertion` you are fine. Using `ExecuteNonQuery`. However, if you want to retrieve data from database, then you could use `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: @Hassan Sir,I want to retrive data from database..

Comment: public SqlDataReader  query(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return dr;.....I tried like this but..showing errror

Comment: I cant see any problems. You want to create so create.

Comment: Check example on this [MSDN-Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add this method

```
public SqlDataReader ReadMe(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return reader;
    }
```

You can call it like this :

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("reading");
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   using(SqlDataReader ourreader = conn.ReadMe(cmd))
        {
         while (ourreader.Read())
               {
               //some code
               }
        }
   conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you @Lamloumi Afif and Mr.Hassan Nisar..ma problem got solved

Comment: @LamloumiAfif. Now that your answer has been selected, you could format it :)

Comment: @Lamloumi Afif and Hassan Nisar :);)